# symfony2 customizing error pages

Tags: symfony

To customize the error page I created an error404.html.twig page to handle the page not found exception like when the user enter an invalid url for example. it works fine but I also need to display different messages according to errors in my application.

For that I use the createNotFoundException() method with a message as parameter but the message doesnt appear when the exception is thrown I always have the message in the error404.html.twig template.
So how can I display the message parameter from the createNotFoundException() in my error page template? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `error404.html.twig` page is a catch around a generic `NotFoundException`: in fact you do see the debug trace in dev mode, but you see the fancy custom HTML in prod.

If you need custom 404 behavior you have to build your `Response` manually, injecting a proper `404 Not Found` status, then a proper body.

```
$product = $em -> getRepository("Acme:Product") -> findOneById( $id );

if($product === NULL)
{

    $response = $this -> render('YourBundle::Errors/404.html.twig', array(
        'message'   => 'blah blah'
    ));

    $response -> setStatus(404);    

    return $response;

}
```

Or you could write a Listener waiting for such event, it's up to you.